# Choosing the Name of a Sefer

Tags: sources-mekorot, jewish-books, names

Is there a kabbalistic preference for the author of a sefer to create a title alluding from a posuk alluding to his name? If so, why?

Comment: I had seen a reference (in a book introduction) that said something like it is best to name a book in equivalent gematria to the author’s name. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @Dr.Shmuel The gematria idea sounds like a great start!

Comment: I believe the phenomenon to have a book title allude to its author’s name was (first?) explicitly recommended by the [Rokeach](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eleazar_of_Worms). IIRC, he doesn’t list preferences vis-a-vis methods of allusion.

Comment: In the preface to Yabia Omer, R' Ovadia Yosef ztz'l discusses this exact concept.

Answer (score 1):

In one of the introductions to קהלות יעקב, The Steipler references an old practice to weave gematria of one’s name into the title of his book.

In his case, קהלות is equal (541) to his second name ישראל. His first name being יעקב of קהלות יעקב.

Additionally, modern books like יביע אומר allude to its author’s name.

`עבדיה יוסף בן יעקב - backwards  יביע`

```
עבדיה יוסף (247) = אומר
```

Comment: This doesn’t answer the q; only provides examples of authors who used such allusions in titles of their books.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if referring to it as a *"kabbalistic preference"* is an accurate idea.

The [R](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eleazar_of_Worms)[okeach of Garmiza](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eleazar_of_Worms) had a tradition to follow such a practice.

Basically, the idea is that a book written by someone is their essence, so to speak. Think of it as the programming line code of who they are. It captures their mind.

Just like the Torah (*the five books of Moshe*) is the essence of G-d's will and the letters of the Torah are, according to the Zohar, G-d's name. This is why one of the explanations of *cleaving to G-d* means to learn Torah.

This concept also has interesting implications in regard resurrection of the dead and the returning of a persons soul to a reconstituted body.